# MakeFile - Avoid certain files when a target is passed

Tags: c, makefile

I am trying to create a target which avoids certain c file. I am doing so because certain file are not compatible and want to avoid them during the build. Bellow is the approach I am using but getting a warring in doing so `warning: overriding commands for target ...`. I do understand the cause of the error but do not know a better approach to this. Please guide me, I am new to MakeFiles. Thanks in advance

```
SRCDIR = ../src
BUILDDIR = build
INCDIR = ../inc

# Compiler to use
CC = gcc

# Include paths for header files
INCLUDES = -I $(INCDIR)

# Compiler flags
# WARNING: Optimization will remove critical code (Problems seen in delay function). Use with caution.
CFLAGS = -Wall -Wextra -g $(INCLUDES) --std=gnu99
CFLAGSNOWARN = -g $(INCLUDES) --std=gnu99

# extra gcc flags used to build dependency files
DEPFLAGS = -MMD -MP

# Paths to required libraries (-L flags)
LFLAGS =

# The specific libraries that project depends on (-l flags)
LIBS = -lreadline -lpthread

# All source files
SRCS = $(wildcard $(SRCDIR)/*.c)
SRCS_1 = $(filter-out $(SRCDIR)/FileToAvoid.c, $(wildcard $(SRCDIR)/*.c))

# All object files
OBJS := $(SRCS:$(SRCDIR)/%.c=%.o)
OBJS_1 := $(SRCS_1:$(SRCDIR)/%.c=%.o)

# name of executable
MAIN = test.exe

# make all
.PHONY: all

# this is the default target
## create temporary .o files and compile main executable
all: $(MAIN)

avoidfile: $(OBJS_1)
    @echo "Compiling executable: $(MAIN)"
    @$(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o $(MAIN) $(OBJS_1) $(LFLAGS) $(LIBS)
    @echo

$(MAIN): $(OBJS)
    @echo "Compiling executable: $(MAIN)"
    @$(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o $(MAIN) $(OBJS) $(LFLAGS) $(LIBS)
    @echo

# Automatically builds all object files from source files
# -c option compiles but does not link (create object files)
# -o is output filename
$(OBJS): %.o : $(SRCDIR)/%.c
    @echo "Compiling object file: $@"
    @$(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(DEPFLAGS) -c $< -o $@
    @echo

$(OBJS_1): %.o : $(SRCDIR)/%.c 
    @echo "Compiling object fileslean: $@"
    @$(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(DEPFLAGS) -c $< -o $@
    @echo
```

Comment: The `@` silencing operators are an antipattern which inhibit any debugging efforts. Take them out for a start (then probably never put them back. Use `make -s` if you don't want to see what you are doing).

Comment: @RahulGupta, OBJS_1 is a subset of OBJS, there is no need to have a static pattern rule for its content.

Comment: You can't have the same file in both the `OBJS` and `OBJS_1` variable.  You should have one list of all the files to avoid, and another list which is all the files _except_ the list of files to avoid.

Comment: @AProgrammer without that static pattern not sure what other approach can  be taken. I am using one make file to build on separate board for example ```make board1``` or ```make board2```. Depending what board it is it will exclude certain files.

Comment: @RahulGupta, have you considered using pattern rules instead of static pattern rules?  In other words, removing the `$(OBJS):` and just using `%.o: $(SRCDIR)/%.c`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since both of your rules to compile are equal, you can make a single rule:

```
$(sort $(OBJS) $(OBJS_1)): %.o : $(SRCDIR)/%.c 
    echo "Compiling object file: $@"
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(DEPFLAGS) -c $< -o $@
```

The `sort` function removes duplicates and is recommended for that purpose even if you don't care about the sorting.

You might think that double-colon rules might help, but beware! The recipes for those are *all* executed, leading to multiple compilations of the same sources.

Comment: @thebusbee Thank you for responding. Doing that work but now it throws ```given more than once in the same rule.```